# Google analytics filter dont seem to be working

Tags: filter, google-analytics

I have set some filters in my GA account but I can still see some sources as I check my traffic source at the end of the day. Here are images showing filter and source traffic, maybe I configured them wrong.

[image: Today's sources]

[image: Filters already in place]

The filter I can see today is the " checkpagerank.net" As I went ahead to set this source in my filter, I realized that there is already a filter for it. 
What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that all Excluding Filters are of custom type and that you are filtering the field by **Campaign Source**. You should create a Custom Filter grouping all the bad referrals using regex. This will work fine for that particular VIEW you are working with. I will try the following approach instead:

1. Go to Admin Select the Account, Property and VIEW you are working with
2. Go to Filters
3. Add New Filter, Type Custon, Select Exclude and from the filter filed dropdown menu select “Campaign Source”
4. Filter Pattern using a regex as simple as this

   ( sub \ . domain \ . com )|( www \ . domain \ . com)|(andsoOn \ . com)

*without the spaces, could not make the regex work

However, If you want to keep excluding every domain individually and you don’t care about keeping that data use the “ referral exclusion list” feature in universal google analytics. Follow this steps

1. Click Admin
2. Select the Account and the Property you are working with
3. Click Tracking Info and Referral Exclusion List.
4. To add a domain, click +ADD REFERRAL EXCLUSION.
5. Enter the Domain name and Create to save.

**Because you are working at property level you can not access this data anymore and you will exclude this data from all your views report

**This is not the best method, your will get those hostname out of your referral report but still they are going to be counted as visits to your site

If this answer works, please Remember to mark it as resolved. :)

Comment: thanks @titico . I created referral exclusion list and so far I dont see these sources coming up again. I do have a confusion thought. I saw my sitename in the referral exclusion list added by default. I totally understand why its there and it makes sense too but i just want to make sure if it should be there. Is this a default thing?

Comment: @shrbisht That it fine, that is to avoid having self-referrals in your Analytics reports. I forgot to mention that if you choose to use the second method you will keep those hostnames away from your referral report but they still will get counted as a visit to your website. I will edit the answer. I will prefer the first method making sure to filtering by "Campaign Source" rather than "Referrals"